# base href in angular 4

Tags: angular, url, href

I have a url like this: `google.com` (which is dynamically coming from backend api)
When I click on the url it is taking me to `localhost:4200/google.com` instead of taking me to `www.google.com`

In my index.html I have this   `<base href="/">`
 Can anyone please help me in this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about url for your api? or UI?

Comment: I'm telling about UI. Api is already connected and i'm getting data back

Comment: Show your code how you redirecting form ui to google.

Comment: <td><a href="{{data.url}}" target="_blank" >{{data.url}}</a></td>

Comment: Why not specify the complete URL (`https://google.com`)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan the url that I'm getting back from api is google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the complete url for correct redirection.

If you dont have http/https in your URL , put // before the URL  like below and pls check

```
<a href="//google.com" >Click</a>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML `<base>` element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. And because of your `<base href="/">` Its looking the url like this

The base url:

```
<base href="/">
```

The anchor:

```
<a href="google.com">Google!</a>
```

Refers to:

```
/google.com
```

And `/` means your project folder root

Comment: I understood that. How can I make changes so that it works?

Comment: Remove the base from the html? Is your whole project depends on this base

Comment: I removed, but I'm still getting localhost:4200/google.com